# The type AdListener cannot be a superinterface of GameActivity

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

i want to change GoogleAdMobAdsSdk by google play services lib, but when i have deleted GoogleAdMobAdsSdk, i had this error : The type AdListener cannot be a superinterface of GameActivity; a superinterface must be an interface.

Can you help me please!

PS : you can fin a part of code here : [migrate to new google play service lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364282/migrate-to-new-google-play-service-lib)

thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

According to the new SDK [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/index.html)

You no longer implement [AdListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener) from your Activity or class. You can use it as an inner class for the [adMob listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/):

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
public void onAdLoaded() {}
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {}
// Only implement methods you need.
});
```

Here's a related SO ticket solved the issue `superinterface must be an interface`: ["The type B cannot be a superinterface of C; a superinterface must be an interface" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435103/the-type-b-cannot-be-a-superinterface-of-c-a-superinterface-must-be-an-interfa)